# Disassemble .NET c# library with dynamic types

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic

I have binaries of .NET library and I have to restore all sources. I used **.NET Reflector** and in most cases it works very well. But now I have problem with dynamic type.
I have following code and I dont really now how to understand it.

```
dynamic obj2 = component;
if (<SetValue>o__SiteContainer0<T>.<>p__Site1 == null)
{
     <SetValue>o__SiteContainer0<T>.<>p__Site1 = CallSite<Func<CallSite, object, bool>>.Create(Binder.UnaryOperation(CSharpBinderFlags.None, ExpressionType.IsTrue, typeof(RecordPropertyDescriptor<T>), new CSharpArgumentInfo[] { CSharpArgumentInfo.Create(CSharpArgumentInfoFlags.None, null) }));
}
if (<SetValue>o__SiteContainer0<T>.<>p__Site2 == null)
{
      <SetValue>o__SiteContainer0<T>.<>p__Site2 = CallSite<Func<CallSite, object, object, object>>.Create(Binder.BinaryOperation(CSharpBinderFlags.None, ExpressionType.NotEqual, typeof(RecordPropertyDescriptor<T>), new CSharpArgumentInfo[] { CSharpArgumentInfo.Create(CSharpArgumentInfoFlags.None, null), CSharpArgumentInfo.Create(CSharpArgumentInfoFlags.UseCompileTimeType, null) }));
}
if (<SetValue>o__SiteContainer0<T>.<>p__Site1.Target(<SetValue>o__SiteContainer0<T>.<>p__Site1, <SetValue>o__SiteContainer0<T>.<>p__Site2.Target(<SetValue>o__SiteContainer0<T>.<>p__Site2, obj2[this.Name], value)))
{
    // some simple code
}
```

Any sugestions?

**EDIT**

I used **ilspy.net** and for me it is even worse

```
Func<CallSite, object, bool> arg_163_0 = RecordPropertyDescriptor<T>.<SetValue>o__SiteContainer0.<>p__Site1.Target;
CallSite arg_163_1 = RecordPropertyDescriptor<T>.<SetValue>o__SiteContainer0.<>p__Site1;
if (RecordPropertyDescriptor<T>.<SetValue>o__SiteContainer0.<>p__Site2 == null)
{
    RecordPropertyDescriptor<T>.<SetValue>o__SiteContainer0.<>p__Site2 = CallSite<Func<CallSite, object, object>>.Create(Binder.UnaryOperation(CSharpBinderFlags.None, ExpressionType.Not, typeof(RecordPropertyDescriptor<T>), new CSharpArgumentInfo[]
    {
        CSharpArgumentInfo.Create(CSharpArgumentInfoFlags.None, null)
    }));
}
Func<CallSite, object, object> arg_15E_0 = RecordPropertyDescriptor<T>.<SetValue>o__SiteContainer0.<>p__Site2.Target;
CallSite arg_15E_1 = RecordPropertyDescriptor<T>.<SetValue>o__SiteContainer0.<>p__Site2;
if (RecordPropertyDescriptor<T>.<SetValue>o__SiteContainer0.<>p__Site3 == null)
{
    RecordPropertyDescriptor<T>.<SetValue>o__SiteContainer0.<>p__Site3 = CallSite<Func<CallSite, Type, object, object, object>>.Create(Binder.InvokeMember(CSharpBinderFlags.None, "Equals", null, typeof(RecordPropertyDescriptor<T>), new CSharpArgumentInfo[]
    {
        CSharpArgumentInfo.Create(CSharpArgumentInfoFlags.UseCompileTimeType | CSharpArgumentInfoFlags.IsStaticType, null),
        CSharpArgumentInfo.Create(CSharpArgumentInfoFlags.None, null),
        CSharpArgumentInfo.Create(CSharpArgumentInfoFlags.UseCompileTimeType, null)
    }));
}
Func<CallSite, Type, object, object, object> arg_159_0 = RecordPropertyDescriptor<T>.<SetValue>o__SiteContainer0.<>p__Site3.Target;
CallSite arg_159_1 = RecordPropertyDescriptor<T>.<SetValue>o__SiteContainer0.<>p__Site3;
Type arg_159_2 = typeof(object);
if (RecordPropertyDescriptor<T>.<SetValue>o__SiteContainer0.<>p__Site4 == null)
{
    RecordPropertyDescriptor<T>.<SetValue>o__SiteContainer0.<>p__Site4 = CallSite<Func<CallSite, object, string, object>>.Create(Binder.GetIndex(CSharpBinderFlags.None, typeof(RecordPropertyDescriptor<T>), new CSharpArgumentInfo[]
    {
        CSharpArgumentInfo.Create(CSharpArgumentInfoFlags.None, null),
        CSharpArgumentInfo.Create(CSharpArgumentInfoFlags.UseCompileTimeType, null)
    }));
}
if (arg_163_0(arg_163_1, arg_15E_0(arg_15E_1, arg_159_0(arg_159_1, arg_159_2, RecordPropertyDescriptor<T>.<SetValue>o__SiteContainer0.<>p__Site4.Target(RecordPropertyDescriptor<T>.<SetValue>o__SiteContainer0.<>p__Site4, component, this.Name), value))))
{
    // some (not so) simple code
}
```

Comment: http://ilspy.net/ It's time to bury Reflector...

Comment: @Dennis does it correctly disassemble this scenario? - the homepage suggests that is "Further Down the Road"

Comment: **ilspy.net** works better than **CodeReflect** but still it gives incomprehensible code

Comment: Just as a comment, this can be made much more comprehensible with judicious use of find and replace (in a text editor, rather than in code), Crucial thing is there's some code that's about setting up calls, and some code about making them. Setting up typically seems to involve a call site, a target, and the same target cast to a call site. Main problem is you can't read the variable names. So, look through the declaration of the site for the method name (as a string) or any `Binder` references, and replace the incomprehensibe stuff with real names. After that, things start to jump out.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is not a problem with your disassembler, it is a problem with your expectations.  Disassemblers in general tend to fall down in any scenario where the C# compiler auto-generates a non-trivial amount of code.  This is certainly the case for the *dynamic* keyword, the compiler makes calls to the binder in Microsoft.CSharp.dll.  And there tend to be a **lot** of it, the dynamic keyword is an expensive hobby.

Things that disassemblers cannot do:

- recover comments in your original source code
- recover const declarations in your original code
- recover the name of local variables in your methods
- cleanly decompile anonymous delegates
- cleanly decompile iterators
- cleanly decompile lambda expressions
- cleanly decompile Linq query comprehensions
- cleanly decompile code that uses dynamic variables.
- cleanly decompile code that uses async/await

Lambdas and Linq got added in 2008 with C# version 3.0 and were instant hits.  Also the year that Lutz Roeder decided that he no longer wanted to work on Reflector and sold it to Redgate.  The timing was almost certainly not a coincidence.

The list above is a decent guide for programmers that are concerned about having their code decompiled.  Just add enough of those constructs to your program and you just don't have to bother with obfuscators anymore.

Meanwhile, this certainly doesn't help you recover your code.  You'll have to do it by hand, relying on your memory of what it might have looked like before.  Of course, first thing to do is to take care of reliable and recoverable source control.  That's a mistake you only make once.

Comment: awesome answer...thnks

Comment: Thats not really answer for my question, but very good explanation. The problem is that lib is not my, so I cannot rely on my memory... I've got only that piece of code and I have to find how to translate it into more understandable code

Comment: Libraries are covered by copyright and almost always distributed with a license agreement.  Which invariably states that you cannot do what you are doing, reverse-engineering or altering the code is typically forbidden.  Check what rights you have in the license agreement you agreed to when you obtained this library.  If obtaining source code is not part of your rights then you'll need to make another agreement with the library owner.  We cannot help you do this.